# Image is overlapping navigation submenus

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

I am having really trouble fixing this overlapping issue on a wordpress site. 
I am working on this http://dev.chrisosheaphotography.com/home/ and i have the sub menu under "Portfolio" but the image is overlapping the sub menu and it is hidden in the back of the image. I want the submenu to appear in front of the image.

I tried using z-index: -1; for #wrapper but it is not working.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an easy fix, just add relative positioning and a positive z-index to:

```
<div class="sub-menu sub-menu-1"></div>
```

e.g.

```
.sub-menu {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1000; 
 }
```

You should also try adding some code and context to your question so that it doesn't get closed for being too localized ..

Comment: Thank you Adrift. You are awesome.